# Window object, window function and Object function

Tags: javascript, object, window

In Chrome and Firefox I can see in console:

```
typeof Window
"function"
typeof window
"object"
```

Could you explain me the difference? I mean I always thought Window is top level object, and now I see it's actually a function, whilst window is an object. Since window is top level object should Window be a method of Window? Little confusing...

Oh, and there's also Object, which is...

```
typeof Object
"function"
```

So what is the relation between those 3 things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `window` is an object and `Window` is its constructor function. Its kind of like `window` is the object and `Window` is the class.
`window` is the global object (not `Window`) so its only natural for `Window` to be a method on it. Since `Window` is a special case you can't just go create another one `new Window()`, like you would with RegExp or Date.

```js
alert(window instanceof Window);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object` is a cunstructor (function) to create an new object, as is `Window`. `window` is an Object.

`window` however is a very special object / variable in JavaScript. Any global variable is contained in window! That's why `window.window.window` is always the same, as it always points the the main Container

You can read more about Window here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window, http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: Could you explain what are the common uses of Window?

Comment: you would create another window object, I'm not aware of a usefull example